# Spring Expression Language Attempted to call method getTime() on null context object

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, spring-el

I have this SPEL expression in Hybris:

attribute->baseProduct.onlineDate that returns a java.util.Date;

However , when I try to get the Time in long :

attribute->baseProduct.onlineDate.getTime()

It throws an exception:

```
Attempted to call method getTime() on null context object
```

I don't understand why is this happening ,since getTime is a public method of java.util.Date. Any hint?

Comment: @HybrisHelp any hint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try `attribute->baseProduct.onlineDate.time`?

The other option is to do as follows:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);//where date is the value you are getting from attribute->baseProduct.onlineDate
```

After this, you can retrieve any part of the date and time from the `cal` object.

Note: with any of the options, please make sure that `attribute->baseProduct.onlineDate` returns a non-null value.

Comment: Can you check this question please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58412355/hybris-mediamodel-how-to-get-bytes