# Hybris MediaModel how to get Bytes

Tags: pdf-generation, media, sap-commerce-cloud, bytearrayinputstream

Is there any way in Hybris to obtain all the bytes from a MediaModel ? When I want to instantiate a PdfReader , I need to pass either the Path of the File OR the ByteArrayInputStream. How can I transform the MediaModel into a Byte Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MediaService

```
@Resource
private MediaService mediaService;
//...
final MediaModel mediaModel= mediaService.getMedia("mediaName");
final InputStream inputStream = mediaService.getStreamFromMedia(mediaModel);
```

Then you can pass InputStream or converting it to the format you want like [ByteArrayInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3496025/2478134)

You can also convert it byte Array like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1264709/2478134)

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```

Comment: I am glad it helped.

Comment: HybrisHelp can you check this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58536975/flexible-search-query-union